# Retrieve multiple data from Array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I asked this question few months ago but at that time i needed to pull just one membership level, now i need to pull every level name, here is array:

```
Array
(
  [success] => 1
  [member] => Array
  (
    [0] => Array
    (
      [Levels] => Array
      (
        [1391447566] => stdClass Object
        (
          [Level_ID] => 1391447566
          [Name] => Team Membership
          [Cancelled] => 
          [CancelDate] => 
          [Pending] => 
          [UnConfirmed] => 
          [Expired] => 
          ExpiryDate] => 1397266537
          [SequentialCancelled] => 
          [Active] => 1
          [Status] => Array
          (
            [0] => Active
          )
          [Timestamp] => 1394588137
          [TxnID] => WL-1-1391447566
        )

        [1391540448] => stdClass Object
        (
          [Level_ID] => 1391540448
          [Name] => Gold Training Membership
          [Cancelled] => 
          [CancelDate] => 
          [Pending] => 
          [UnConfirmed] => 
          [Expired] => 
          [ExpiryDate] => 1396642789
          [SequentialCancelled] => 
          [Active] => 1
          [Status] => Array
          (
            [0] => Active
          )

          [Timestamp] => 1393967989
          [TxnID] => WL-1-1391540448
        )

        [1391540567] => stdClass Object
        (
          [Level_ID] => 1391540567
          [Name] => Platinum Training Membership
          [Cancelled] => 
          [CancelDate] => 
          [Pending] => 
          [UnConfirmed] => 
          [Expired] => 
          [ExpiryDate] => 1397302237
          [SequentialCancelled] => 
          [Active] => 1
          [Status] => Array
          (
            [0] => Active
          )

          [Timestamp] => 1394623837
          [TxnID] => WL-1-1391540567
        )

      )

      [PayPerPosts] => Array
      (
      )

    )

  )

  [supported_verbs] => Array
  (
    [0] => GET
    [1] => PUT
    [2] => DELETE
  )

)
```

What I need is to pull Name of Level which is inside an object that has diffrent number every time and add it to an array which i need to save in DB. One solution, just to pull info, wass:

```
foreach ($response["member"][0]["Levels"] AS $level_key => $level_val) {
$level_name = $level_key->Name;
    echo 'Name: '.$level_name;
}
```

but its not pulling anything, just echoing "name" 3 times.

This was the code i used to pull only one name:

```
$levels = $response["member"][0]["Levels"];
$firstLevel = array_shift(array_values($levels));
$membership = $firstLevel->Name;
```

Thanks!

Comment: $level_name = $level_key->Name; should be $level_name = $level_val->Name ;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$level_name = $level_val->Name;
```

`$level_key` is an integer value with level ID (?). `$level_val` is your level object with data.

Comment: @GoranJakovljevic Remember to accept this answer with the tick on the left and your other recent ones too.